# Java rock-paper-scissors program does not print right output

Tags: java

**I want my program to display what the computer chose.**

But instead, it sometimes does not, or sometimes it does display

- `The computer chose Rock`
- `The computer chose Paper`
- `The computer chose Scissors`

This happens even if i follow the same input pattern.

**Output when the user inputs 1 , 2 , 3 in order-**

[image: img_1]

**Similarly, output when the user again inputs 1 , 2 , 3 in order-**

[image: img_2]

**Output when the user inputs randomly-**

[image: img_3]

**Code-**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RockPaperScissors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random play= new Random();
        System.out.println("Best of three of Rock paper scissors!");
        int win=0;
        int i =1;
        while(i<=3){
            int number=play.nextInt(3);
            System.out.println("Press 1 for Rock");
            System.out.println("Press 2 for Paper");
            System.out.println("Press 3 for Scissor");
            int ch=scanner.nextInt();
            if(number==1)
                System.out.println("The computer chose Rock");
            if(number==2)
                System.out.println("The computer chose Paper");
            if(number==3)
                System.out.println("The computer chose Scissor");

            if(ch==1 && number==1)
                System.out.println("Draw");
            else if(ch==1 && number==2)
                System.out.println("Lost");
            else if(ch==1 && number==3){
                System.out.println("Won");
                win++;}
            else if(ch==2 && number==1){
                System.out.println("Won");
                win++;}
            else if(ch==2 && number==2)
                System.out.println("Draw");
            else if(ch==2 && number==3)
                System.out.println("Lost");
            else if(ch==3 && number==1)
                System.out.println("Lost");
            else if(ch==3 && number==2){
                System.out.println("Won");
                win++;}
            else if(ch==3 && number==3)
                System.out.println("Draw");

            i++;

        }
        if(win==3 || win==2)
            System.out.println("You won the game!");
        else
            System.out.println("Aww you lost the game.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `int number = play.nextInt(3)`. This method returns either 0, 1, or 2 (documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-)), whereas your code expects 1, 2, 3.

A simple fix would be to do `int number = play.nextInt(3) + 1`.